# Best way to run PHP with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

What is the best way to run PHP with Nginx?

1. Run Nginx with PHP FastCGI
2. Run Nginx as a reverse proxy while Nginx forwards request to Apache

Comment: It should read FastCGI instead of CGI. nginx supports CGI only through a hack (http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxSimpleCGI) at this time.

Comment: Yeah should have told PHP FastCGI
Updated; Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need support for htaccess or any other Apache features, option 2, otherwise option 1.

Answer (score 7):

I would say option one, and look into using php-fpm with nginx, it works great.

Comment: +1 A helpful tutorial on the subject can be found on HowToForge - [Installing PHP 5.3, Nginx And PHP-fpm On Ubuntu/Debian](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian)